# IntelliJ Idea does not always run my code as expected while calling java from bash does

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am learning to build a game following 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0T1U0kbu1Sk 
However, when I run the code from IntelliJ Idea, sometimes it doesn't render and somtimes it does.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8EH7.png)
It's not rendering.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7gpv.png)
It's rendering.

Then I try to run it using a terminal, it runs properly every time.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkIOX.jpg)
Why's that? 
Here is my config
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2Rl5.png)

Game.java is here
`

```
package com.tutorial.main;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.util.Random;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1569537827497786082L;

    public static final int WIDTH = 640, HEIGHT = WIDTH / 12 * 9;

    private Thread thread;
    private Boolean running = false;

    private Handler handler;

    private Random r;

    public Game() {
        handler = new Handler();

        new Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Let's Build a Game!", this);

        r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            handler.addObject(new Player(r.nextInt(WIDTH), r.nextInt(HEIGHT), ID.Player));
        }
//        handler.addObject(new Player(200, 200, ID.Player));
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
        running = true;
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        try {
            thread.join();
            running = false;
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
        double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
        double delta = 0;
        long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int frames = 0;
        while(running){
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;
            while (delta >= 1) {
                tick();
                delta--;
            }
            if(running)
                render();
            frames++;

            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
                timer += 1000;
                System.out.println("FPS: " + frames);
                frames = 0;
            }
        }
        stop();
    }

    private void tick() {
        handler.tick();

    }

    private void render() {
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null) {
            this.createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }

        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        handler.render(g);

        g.dispose();
        bs.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Game();
    }
}
```

`

---

Some Updates:

I was using Oracle's Java SE 9 JDK on macOS High Sierra 10.13.1.

I tried to use Eclipse and the problem showed up sometimes, but not so frequently.

I also tried to build and run the source code using openjdk 1.7 https://github.com/alexkasko/openjdk-unofficial-builds The problem still existed but became less often.

I tried it on Windows 10 using OpenJDK 1.8 https://github.com/ojdkbuild/ojdkbuild and the bug never showed up.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: @GhostCat use the `[edit]` shortcut in your comment to make an [edit] link, rather than saying "edit".

Comment: @AndyTurner Neat one, thanks. Going to update my AUTO texts immediately!

Comment: @GhostCat  Thanks for the advice! This is my first time to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out the reason myself. It's the fault of macOS High Sierra and Java AWT package!
Java AWT is a deprecated package and macOS does not support it very well.

So, the reason of properly displaying the frame while the Canvas rendering is bad is that the code is using Java swing package to create the Window (JFrame) and the Canvas is from AWT.

Later I try some other features of awt, such as java.awt.event.KeyEvent and they sometimes fail, too.

So, I think the best solution is stop using java awt package on macOS.